# JavaScript - Puppeteer timeout equal zero meaning and behavior

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am a little bit confused about the timeout of "waitFor" kind of functions.
What would happen when "waitFor" function is called with "timeout" set to zero?

```
await page.waitFor("#button", {timeout: 0}
```

Will it wait "forever" or skip waiting at all? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same way as the [other](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) `waitFor` functions:

> - `timeout`  maximum time to wait for in milliseconds. Defaults to `30000` (30 seconds). Pass `0` to disable timeout.

So, `{ timeout: 0 }` will wait forever. Without a `timeout` property, it'll wait for 30 seconds before timing out by itself.

Comment: This is explanation I needed. Thank you.